# Nabla on fraction $\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)=\left(\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{r}\right)\cdot(\nabla r)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

In connection with introduction to electro dynamics, we deduced that
$$\frac{\vec r}{r^3}=-\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$$
This is fairly obvious for three dimensions, but we did it in $n$ dimensions.

In the process of derivation, there was the following step included:
$$-\nabla\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)=-\left(\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{r}\right)\cdot(\nabla r)$$
Once again, the correctness of this can be easily checked in three dimensions, but it seemed kind of obvious that this is generally true. Is this a commonly known rule? And how does one derive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\vec{v}=\operatorname{grad}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$$
Then we have that
$$\begin{align}
v_i&=\partial_i \frac{1}{r}\\
&= \partial_i r^{-1}\\
&= -r^{-2} (\partial_i r)\\
&= -r^{-2} (\partial_i \sqrt{x_jx_j})\\
&= -r^{-2} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_jx_j}} \partial_i (x_jx_j)\\
&= -r^{-2} \frac{1}{2 r} 2(\partial_ix_j)x_j\\
&=-r^{-3} \delta_{ij}x_j\\
&=-\frac{x_i}{r^3}
\end{align}$$
i.e.
$$\vec{v}=-\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}=\operatorname{grad}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$$

Comment: But you've implied the part I don't understand again - why is $\partial_ir^{-1}=-r^{-2}(\partial_ir)$?

Comment: @MetaColon It's the chain rule: $\frac{\partial r^{-1}}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial r^{-1}}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}$

Comment: Oh I see, it's because you firstly derive the outer and then the inner part. Thanks!

Comment: @MetaColon Yes. You're welcome!

Comment: @Botond very nice answer (+1)

Comment: @the_candyman Thank you!